# Google Cloud Storage permission denied

Tags: google-cloud-storage, permission-denied, bucket

I set up a `Cloud Run` which uses a `Bucket` on `Cloud Storage`. Locally I run it in a `Docker Container`, the credentials are passed using a `json` file, created and downloaded from `IAM & Admin`, and it works. When deployed, writing to the bucket throws an error:

```
{
    500 unable to sign bytes: googleapi: Error 403: Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob' denied on resource (or it may not exist).
    Details:
    [{
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "domain": "iam.googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
            "permission": "iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob"
        },
        "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED"
    
    }]
    []
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 8):

I had to add the `Service Account Token Creator` to the service account. I did it, but it did not work anyway because there is the need to deploy a new version of the service, so:

1. Add the role `Service Account Token Creator`
2. Deploy new version of the service

Comment: This is the correct answer for Cloud Run - I am using Cloud Run and my Cloud Run instance runs as the default service account: 123456789-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com and I had to add Service Account Token Creator and redeploy the service. Thank you very very much Emaborsa!